# How to display a Ridge Regression using the Stargazer package? (error: Unrecognized object type)

Tags: r, linear-regression, stargazer

I am trying to use the stargazer package to display a Ridge Regression, but the error appears: unrecognized object type. Do any of you know how to fix it? Or know other packages that show a good table with the regression results in R? I appreciate any help you can provide.

```
#Here is the main code used for one of the regressions:

base_sem_NAs_padronizada <- base_sem_NAs %>% 
  mutate(
    HHI = as.numeric(scale(HHI)),
    log_pib = as.numeric(scale(log(pib_milhares))),
    pib_milhares = as.numeric(scale(pib_milhares)),
    log_pib_per_capita = as.numeric(scale(log(pib_per_capita))),
    pib_per_capita = as.numeric(scale(pib_per_capita)),
    incremento = as.numeric(scale(incremento)), 
    log_pib_agricola = as.numeric(scale(log(pib_agricola))),
    pib_agricola = as.numeric(scale(pib_agricola)),
    # log_pib_industria = as.numeric(scale(log(pib_industria))),
    pib_industria = as.numeric(scale(pib_industria)),
    populacao = as.numeric(scale(populacao)), 
    ano_de_eleicao = as.numeric(scale(ano_de_eleicao)),
    nuvem = as.numeric(scale(nuvem)),
    area_km2 = as.numeric(scale(area_km2)),
    homicidio = as.numeric(scale(homicidio)),
    idhm_2010 = as.numeric(scale(idhm_2010)),
    incremento = incremento - mean(incremento) #centralizar resposta
  )

reg1 <- lm(
  incremento ~ pib_per_capita + ano_de_eleicao + nuvem  + homicidio + idhm_2010 - 1, # + log_pib_industria,
  data = base_sem_NAs_padronizada
)

beta_original1 <- reg1$coefficients #para reg1
p1 <- length(beta_original1) #para reg1
sighat2_1 <- summary(reg1)$sigma^2 #para reg1

novo_k1 <- function(beta) p*sighat2_1/(t(beta)%*%beta) #para reg1
novo_beta1 <- function(k) { #para reg1
  cur_fit1 <- ridge::linearRidge(
    incremento ~ pib_per_capita + ano_de_eleicao + nuvem  + homicidio + idhm_2010 - 1, # + log_pib_industria,
    lambda = k,
    data = base_sem_NAs_padronizada,
    scaling = "none"
  )
  return(cur_fit1$coef)
}

kk1 <- novo_k1(beta_original1) #para reg1
for(j in 1:200) kk1 <- kk1 %>% novo_beta1() %>% novo_k1() #para reg1

ridge_fit1 <- ridge::linearRidge( #para reg1
  incremento ~ pib_per_capita + ano_de_eleicao + nuvem  + homicidio + idhm_2010 - 1, # + log_pib_industria,
  lambda = kk1,
  data = base_sem_NAs_padronizada,
  scaling = "none"
)

ridge_fit1 %>% 
  summary()

stargazer(ridge_fit1)
```

% Error: Unrecognized object type.

Comment: Have you tried using `glmnet` package?